# Is the periodic table ordered by bonded atoms and does that change the electron configurations and ordering?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals, periodic-trends, elements, periodic-table

In my book (Mortimer, The Basic Knowledge of Chemistry) the electron structure of the elements is introduced, there the relative energies of the atomic orbitals are shown:

*1s < 2s < 2p < 3s < 3p < 4s < 3d < 4p < 5s < 4d < 5p < 6s...* (Tab. 6.22)

Then the aufbau principle is explained and on a whole page each period with its exceptions is gone through with the electron configurations.

Up to that point, everything was understandable, but the last paragraph now says the following:

> The electron configurations mentioned in the preceding paragraphs and in Table 6.6 are based on measurements of unbound single atoms in the gas phase. For the periodic table, however, the classification according to chemical properties is decisive, i.e. of bonded atoms. For bonded atoms of the d- and f-block (not the s-block), the energetic sequence of the orbitals is somewhat different from that shown in Fig. 6.22, so that the d-levels come just below the following s-levels (see marginal columns). This does not affect the order of the elements in the periodic table, but it does affect the chemical properties.

Is the periodic system ordered with the properties as if they were bound atoms? Do these bound atoms also have a different electron configuration or still the same as unbound, but the energy sequences are now shifted (do the electrons change their orbital as soon as the energy sequence changes) and why doesn't that affect the order of the elements in the periodic table?

And why can d-block elements still be classified as d-block when energetic sequence changes?

Comment: Have a look at some other versions of the periodic table: last I check, there are more than 100! This tells you that ‘one size doesn’t fit all’. Put another way: there are horses for courses! My favorite is this wonderful 1949 periodic table by John Drury Clark: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/128563/79678.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the periodic system ordered with the properties as if they were
> bound atoms?

I think it will help you understand the context better if you read a little about the history of the periodic table. The repeating pattern of the elemental properties was recognized long before electrons were discovered. People had  a very little understanding of the structure of atom then (electron, neutron and protons) and we still do not know enough. It is called a periodic table because the elemental and chemical properties in the bulk repeat regularly after certain periods (similar to periodic mathematical functions). Thus, the periodic table has nothing to do with electron configuration at this moment.

Much later, when people started to learn about how hydrogen, helium, and other lighter atoms, such as Li/Na, emitted light in the *gas phase*, they realized that the electrons in a given atom must have different bound state energies with the nucleus. This is what Mortimer is discussing unbound single atoms in the gas phase. You simply heat or electrically excite a given element such that the given element is vaporized into gaseous atoms. For example, $\ce{H2}$ will dissociate into hydrogen atoms and emit light in an electric discharge tube.

All electron configurations were based on extensive calculations of the hydrogen atom. A theory that closely matched the experimental results of the hydrogen spectrum was retained, and the previous theory was discarded. Based on the possible electron configuration of hydrogen and helium, researchers extended these ideas to other heavier elements, too much of an extrapolation. Therefore, for heavier elements, consider the concept of electron configurations with a grain of salt, i.e., do not worry about it too much until and unless you wish to seriously pursue theoretical chemistry or physics. Otherwise, there is a lot of hand-waving esp. in general chemistry textbooks.

> Do these bound atoms also have a different electron configuration

Yes, in a sense they are called molecular orbitals instead of atomic orbitals.

Answer (score 0):

The periodic table has been and still is not directly related to the electronic structure of the elements. It is obtained by alining the elements by order of increasing atomic masses, then cutting this long series into groups just after each noble gas, and superimposing the obtained groups of elements. This is all. As the groups do not have the same number of elements, some further breaks have been done to take care of this fact. But the electronic structure does not intervene in the definition of the table.

Comment: So is the block division more of an approximation? The division into S, P, D, F blocks only works for unbound atoms (because if the energy sequence of bound elements changes and, for example, 3d goes below 4s, some elements would also have to change into another block because the last added electron would go in the other subshell)?